# jQuery animate triggers .complete callback 5 times

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can't catch my mistake.. Please help to figure out why callback of animate triggers several times.

Code below scroll textblock from top to bottom. "step" of animate moves custom scrollbar...

```
currentText.stop().animate({
                top: "-"+textHeight+"px"}, 
                {   
                    duration: durationOfAutoScroll, 
                    step: function(currentTop) {  
                        var positionY = currentTop;
                        if (positionY < curState.maskHeight - curState.textHeight) positionY = curState.maskHeight - curState.textHeight;
                        if (positionY > 0) positionY = 0;
                        var scrollPosition = -positionY * curState.scrollHeight / (curState.textHeight - curState.maskHeight);
                        curState.scrollerTop = scrollPosition;
                        $(".news-text .scroll-bar .scroller").css("top", scrollPosition);
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        //jQuery.dequeue(currentText);
                        currentText.attr("data-state", 0);
                        onEndScroll();
                }
            }
            );
```

Comment: could you post the code of the onEndScroll function ?

Answer (score 0):

This means that your collection (*currentText*) has `5` elements, the callback is fired once for each element, this is the expected behavior.

If that's not what you want, you can create a promise object and use the `done` method:

```
currentText.stop().animate({
    top: "..."
}, {
    duration: '...',
    step: function () {
      // ...
    },
}).promise().done(function () {
    // done
});
```